# Load Angular 2 component to area

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a website, where a settings dialog should be loaded in a specific are, when clicked on a button.
The settings dialog is a component which loads data from REST endpoints.
I don't want to insert the component and just hide it, since I want to save resources.
What's the correct Angular 2 way to do this?

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. What does "loaded in a specific area" mean exactly, and also what does "load" mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngIf` for that kind of purpose, it will insert element only if the condition is true

```
<div *ngIf="condition">
    <!-- Content present in DOM only if condition == true -->
</div>
```

This way your data won't be loaded at runtime, but when the component is inserted (=> when the condition becomes true).

EDIT : Load based on shouldBeLoaded, then show / hide based on shouldBeDisplayed ; once shouldBeLoaded is set to true, its value should not change

```
<component *ngIf="shouldBeLoaded" *ngShow="shouldBeDisplayed">
</component>
```

Comment: Does this reload the component when I hide and display it again?

Comment: Yep, you may use a second variable with `ngShow` to only hide/show the component when loaded ; i edited my post with an example

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to do that:

1. `<div [hidden]="condition"> content </div>` it will create `content`, but hide it when `condition` is `true`
2. `<div *ngIf="condition"> content </div>` it will create `content` when `condition` is true, otherwise it won't